# Как добавить текст на изображение?

Tags: c#, изображения

Использую кастомный шрифт не установленный в систему. Изменение шрифта для кнопки работает, но на изображение никакого текста не выводится. Никаких ошибок не выводит.

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile("Axixa.otf");
Font fnt = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 8, FontStyle.Regular);
button1.Font = fnt; // This code change font correctly

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("1.png");

RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
StringFormat format = new StringFormat()
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
};
g.DrawString("123, 123", fnt, Brushes.Red, rectf, format);

g.Flush();

g.Save();
```

Comment: Этот шрифт можно где-то скачать, чтобы попробовать? В целом ваш код правильный, с другим шрифтом всё работает. Как вы смотрите получившееся изображение? Если что, метод `Graphics.Save` **не** сохраняет изображение.

Comment: Александр, хм.. Оказывается мой код даже на стандартном шрифте не пашет. Что не так?

Comment: Этот код пашет, текст добавляется на изображение. Как вы потом проверяете получившееся изображение?

Comment: Открываю через просмотр изображений

Comment: Изображение сохраняется вызовом `bmp.Save`?